# Exacttarget SQL Query Help: Find all Subscribers that opened at least 2 emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver

I am trying to write a query to identify all subscribers that opened at least 2 emails in the last 6 months.

I will pull from a data extension called "Clients" and look for all opens in the "_open" Data view. Since the "_open" data view only holds 6 months worth of data, I will not enter a date constraint.

My sample query is as follows:

select *
from clients

where EmailAddress  in (Select  Distinct SubscriberKey FROM _open)

This query identifies all unique subscribers (by emailaddress) in the Client DE that opened any email in the last 6 months.

I am struggling to modify the query so that it pulls all records where a subscriber  opened at least 2 separate emails.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would this work? - in query do a join on _opens where _opens is GROUP BY SubscriberKey HAVING COUNT(SubscriberKey) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve do a join on _opens where _opens is GROUP BY SubscriberKey HAVING COUNT(SubscriberKey) > 1